# How do you dynamically set nginx root based on location?

Tags: regex, nginx

I can't find any information on doing this specifically but I am basically trying to catch a location like:

```
http://domain.com/project/Content/Images/image.png
```

and I want it to point to root like so:

```
/var/www/$project/Content/Images/image.png
```

This is what I tried to put together but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
location ~ ^/(?<project>.+)/Content/^(?<content>.+)$ {
    root /var/www/$project/Content/$content;
}
```

I't doesn't seem to be catching this location as I get a 404 error which is setup with a php page I have with try_files in a location for /. This makes me think the regexp is wrong but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you give a little more information in regards to it "not working"? Is the root being updated at all? Are you getting an incorrect root value?

Comment: I'm sorry I did one of the things that bothers me the most. I updated the question with a little more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are really close. You have an extra ^ in your regex search string. ^ means "match from the beginning of the line"

```
location ~ ^/(?<project>.+)/Content/(?<content>.+)$ {
    root /var/www/$project/Content/$content;
}
```

Comment: Added a edit to your answer that makes it work exactly as I expected. Thanks for the help!